# What options are there for verifying that mturk is requesting my ExternalQuestion and not a 3rd party?

Tags: python, django, authorization, mechanicalturk

I have a django application that I want to host a form on to use as the template for an ExternalHit on Amazon's Mechanical Turk. I've been trying to figure out ways that I can make it so only mturk is authorized to view this document.

One idea I've been considering is looking at the request headers and confirming that the request came from Amazon. However, I couldn't find any documentation regarding any of these topics and I am worried that if the source of the request ever changes the page will become inaccessible to mturk.

Anyone have any suggestions or solutions that they have implemented?

Fyi, I'm using python/django/boto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every request from AWS will include additional URL parameters: `workerId`, `assignmentId`, `hitId`. That's probably the easiest way to identify a request coming from MTurk. There may be headers, as well, but they're not documented anywhere.

Comment: Considering using assignmentId + some form of uri obfuscation. Thanks, we'll see what ends up working.

Comment: Do you know if the hitId is sent during preview mode? The documentation only mentions that assignmentId will have a special value during preview mode.

Comment: It should be included. The reason assignmentId is weird is that it is not generated until the task is accepted.

Comment: That is what I figured. Once I get an environment to test this stuff on I will accept your answer as it lead me to the solution I'm considering. Till then I'd like to see if anyone else has suggestions. Thanks man!

Comment: I ended up keeping track of the hitIds of my HITS and which of my resources they apply to. Then to validate my requests I make sure that the correct resource is being requested for the correct hitId.